# Maximize value of (a+b) such that (a*a-b*b = N).

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a value N, find the maximize value of value of (a+b) such that a^2-b^2 = N

Note: The value of N is odd. a and b are integers.

For eg if n = 1

The value of a*a - b*b is 1. The maximum value occurs when a=1 and b=0.

Thus, a+b = 1.

I know it's anser will always be n.

But can anyone help me in knowing that how it answer will always be n.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a \neq b$. $a+b=\frac N {a-b}$ Since $|a-b| \geq 1$ we get $a+b \leq N$. The value $N$ is attained when $a=\frac {N+1} 2$ and $b=\frac {N-1} 2$